# How the use unit test in cmake in language C?

Tags: c, unit-testing, cmake

I have a C project:

```
.
├── build
├── bin
│   └── parser
├── CMakeLists.txt
├── configure.h.in

├── inc
│   ├── configure.h
│   ├── diam_dict.h
│   └── unit_tests.h
├── README.txt
├── src
│   └── diam_dict.c
└── testing
    └── unit_tests.c
```

I want to put unit tests in the directory "**testing**", in the file "**unit_tests.c**". 

I want to test all the functions of the file "**src/diam_dict.c**", what should I do to let "**unit_tests.c**" know where are the functions to test?

[what should I write in the file "**unit_tests.c**" and the top level cmake file "**CMakeLists.txt**"?]

(I should call all the functions of the source code file "**diam_dict.c**" to test them)



ps: The header file "**diam_dict.h**" contains all the prototypes of the functions in the source file "**diam_dict.c**", and the header file "**unit_tests.h**" cotains all the prototypes of the test file "**unit_tests.c**".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

CMake is a build system, so you can combine it with any unit testing framework you wish.

As a matter of fact, CTest can call executables and check their result value, which allows some testing. But it is usually less fine granular compared to real unit test a known from dedicated unit testing frameworks.

Comment: I am using CUnit for this project in fact.

Comment: This is not reflected by your question.